# Spring Security, Basic Auth with Dynamic Role and Dynamic Url

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I am using Spring Security 4.1.1

I didn't try it but I want dynamic permission for any user in my mysql database and configure security like below.

```
For    @Order(1)
....
 http
              .antMatcher("/{managerpathId}/{localuserpathId}/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                  .anyRequest().hasRole("{localuserID}")

For    @Order(2)
...
http
              .antMatcher("/{managerpathId}/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                  .anyRequest().hasRole("{LocalAdminID}")
For    @Order(3)
...
http
              .antMatcher("/{masteradminpathId}/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                  .anyRequest().hasRole("{MasterID}")
```

Using by user repository, How should i configure my security?Is it a good solution, are there any better solution?